# Python Pandas: Average column if

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

In MS Excel there is a handy formula =AVERAGEIF(values, criteria). 
Is there a similar way to average values within one columns that conform to certain condition?

I have a column of values in my data frame from -5000 to +5000. 
I need to average values between -5000 <= x < 0 
And separately average values between 0 < x <= 5000.

NOTE: I'd like to avoid applying Boolean mask and therefore creating new dataframe, because I have lots of columns.

Any help, suggestions, or edits to this post are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Using Boolean mask actually does what I need.

```
df[df>0].mean(axis=0,skipna=True,numeric_only=True)
```

It returns as many  **single** values as I have columns. Perfect!